# Radio Button Calculations

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have two files...

- **Poll**

Here the page is a poll, for the user to check some radio buttons with different values, for future calculations.

```js
< script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" > < /script>
<script>
function show_object(){
  var error = 0;
  var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
  var poll1 = document.vacation.poll1;
  if(poll1.value ==="")
    {
  $("#errgen").fadeIn(2000);
         error = 1;
    }
  else{
   $("#errgen").fadeOut(2000);
    error = 0;
}
  var poll2 = document.vacation.poll2;
  if(poll2.value ==="")
    {
  $("#errgen1").fadeIn(2000);
        error = 1;
    }
  else{
    $("#errgen1").fadeOut(2000);
    error = 0;
}
  var poll3 = document.vacation.poll3;
  if(poll3.value ==="")
    {
  $("#errgen2").fadeIn(2000);
        error = 1;
    }
  else{
    $("#errgen2").fadeOut(2000);
    error = 0;
}
  
    if(error == 0)
    {
      window.location.href = "/poll-result";
    }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

```css
#errgen {
  display: none;
  color: #ff0000;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 10px;
}
#errgen1,
#errgen2
{
  display: none;
  color: #ff0000;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form id="vacation" name="vacation">
  Question
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="poll1" value="0" />Answer
  <input type="radio" name="poll1" value="1" />Answer
  <input type="radio" name="poll1" value="2" />Answer
  <input type="radio" name="poll1" value="3" />Answer
  <span id="errgen">Select one of the fields</span>
  <br>
  <br>
  <!-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
  Question
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="poll2" value="0" />Answer
  <input type="radio" name="poll2" value="1" />Answer
  <input type="radio" name="poll2" value="2" />Answer
  <input type="radio" name="poll2" value="3" />Answer
  <span id="errgen1" class="error">Select one of the fields</span>
  </br>
  </br>
  <!-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
  Question
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="poll3" value="0" />Answer
  <input type="radio" name="poll3" value="1" />Answer
  <input type="radio" name="poll3" value="2" />Answer
  <input type="radio" name="poll3" value="3" />Answer
  <span id="errgen2" class="error">Select one of the fields</span>
  </br>
  </br>
  <!-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="return show_object();" />
</form>
```

- **Poll-Result**

Here, is the results page. For each result there will be a different message, but I can't seem to redirect the Poll page to the Result Page with the calculations made.

```
<div class="poll">

            <strong>
            <?php 

                 $sum = $_POST['poll1'] + $_POST['poll2'] + $_POST['poll3'];
                 echo "Your result is ".$sum; ?>.</strong><br><br>
                 <p class="justify">
                 <?php

                 switch (true) {
                    case ($sum <= 4):
                        echo "Message1";
                        break;
                    case ($sum >= 5 && $sum <= 9):
                        echo "Message2";
                        break;

                 }


            ?>
        </p>
</div>
```

Is there a way to when I press the button, be redirected to the Poll-Result file with the calculations made and the message for each result?

Thanks

Comment: You need to set the `action` attribute to your form to the URL of the PHP page. For example, `<form id="vacation" name="vacation" action="poll_result.php">`.

Comment: Thanks
But that doesn't seem to work. Myabe because of the window.location.href?

Comment: Try changing this: `onclick="return show_object();" ` to `onclick="javascript:show_object();" `. And don't set the `window.location.href`, if you want to allow the form to pass, just return `true`, and set the `action` attribute according to the previous comment.

Comment: still nothing.If I change the type of the button to "submit" the calculations are made, even if not all the radio buttons are checked.

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: I did. Thanks so much for your help ^^